# Redmine 'mentions' plugin stopped working

Tags: plugins, redmine

I've installed the Redmine Mentions plugin from:
https://github.com/arkhitech/redmine_mentions

And it worked perfect until a few days. I couldn't find helpful information on the internet and the author didn't reply as well so It'd be great if someone could advise on this one.
No changes took place on the server, no config modifications...and suddenly the mention 'trigger' (which is currently '@') isn't working.

I've tried to restart, reinstall and reconfig the trigger but **none of these solved the issue**.

Here's a little bit of info on the system:

Environment:
  Redmine version                2.4.2.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p484 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.16
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2

Please advise,
**Much appreciated!**

Thanks,
Talbion.

Comment: check your logs carefully - maybe some info is there

Comment: Thanks Gotva. I've checked the 'production.log' and found no errors or related messages. Couldn't find any other relevant log (of mentions itself..?).
If you're aware of such a log file (that can help on this matter) other than 'production.log', please tell me and I'll have it checked.
THANKS!

Comment: I think you can debug plugin yourself. Look at [this](https://github.com/arkhitech/redmine_mentions/blob/master/lib/redmine_mentions/journal_patch.rb#L7) - there are 3 places to check. Line 8: is condition `self.journalized.is_a?(Issue) && self.notes.present?` true? Line 15: does scanning find users? Line 18: is user found `if user = User.find_by_login(username)`?

Comment: I suggest to start from the last point. Maybe users have changed their `username`. It looks the most perspective supposition

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've eventually managed to fix this by removing a plugin called 'a_common_libs' which was a dependency for another plugin that's been installed on the server - 'Usability plugin'. At first I uninstalled the Usability plugin (our redmine version 2.4 wasn't supported by this plugin) but that didn't solve the 'mentions' issue. Later I've decided to uninstall it's dependency as well...and it looks good.
(btw, for whoever is curious about the uninstallation process - it consisted of MOVING the plugin folder and restarting Redmine. That's it).

So...I don't know exactly how both plugins are related but somehow the removal of the common libraries fixed mentions.

Thanks again for your help.
Talbion.